# How can I detect last key pressed in a Flutter textformfield?

Tags: flutter

I have a TextFormField in which I want to detect if the LAST key pressed was an "@" letter. I don't mean the last letter of the full text changed, I mean the last typed key was "@". For example, they could move the cursor back to middle of string and then type "@" key, and I want to detect this.

I am trying to use the RawKeyboardListener, but it's not working. In this example, I simply am trying to see if I can detect a key was pressed to fire the onkey event, but it does not fire?

How can I detect the last key pressed in this example?

```
  RawKeyboardListener(
    focusNode: FocusNode(),
    onKey: (event) {
      print('key detected');
          if(event.isKeyPressed(LogicalKeyboardKey.at)){
            print('@ key pressed');
          }
    },
    child: TextFormField(
      controller: textEditingController,
      onChanged: (comment) => checkCommentString(comment),
      minLines: 1,
      maxLines: 3,
      autocorrect: false,
      enableSuggestions: false,
      textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none,
    ),
  ),
```

also tried, but did not work:

```
 TextFormField(
            focusNode: FocusNode(onKey: (_,event){
              print('key pressed');
              return KeyEventResult.handled;
            }),
            controller: textEditingController,
            onChanged: (comment) => checkCommentString(comment),
            minLines: 1,
            maxLines: 3,
            autocorrect: false,
            enableSuggestions: false,
            textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none,
          ),
```

also tried:

```
TextField(
            focusNode: FocusNode(onKeyEvent: (node,event){
              print('key pressed');
              return KeyEventResult.handled;
            }),
            controller: tx,
            // onChanged: (comment) => checkCommentString(comment),
            minLines: 1,
            maxLines: 3,
            autocorrect: false,
            enableSuggestions: false,
            textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.none,
          ),
```

Comment: tried `FocusOnKeyCallback? onKey` and/or
`FocusOnKeyEventCallback? onKeyEvent` callbacks of `FocusNode` ctor? but honestly it smells like a `XY problem` to me

Comment: Well, let me restate the problem without attempting a solution. I have a textformfield and I need to detect whenever the user enters the @ key, so I can dynamically show them a list of users they want to mention in the comment. Very same functionality like slack...anywhere you type @ key, it detects to show list of users. How might I solve that?

Comment: so you want some kind of "inline" dropdown list immediately following `@` character? by "inline" i mean it is a part of `TextFormField`'s content?

Comment: basically, yes. FYI, it doesn't need to be part of textformfield. In my implementation, it would show names below the textformfield, when they click the name, it inserts the username into the textformfield wherever the cursor is.

Comment: ok, so use `TextFormField` with `focusNode: myFocusNode` and try one of those 2 callbacks that i mentioned in my first comment when creating `myFocusNode` - but you could also override [buildTextSpan](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/TextEditingController/buildTextSpan.html) and build `WidgetSpan` containing some "inline" dropdown - something like https://pastebin.com/Puw3hzwN - here `ActionChip` is used as an "inline" widget

Comment: posted an attempt to use the focusNode() on the TextFormField ...still does not detect they keypress.

Comment: i just tried `TextField(focusNode: FocusNode(onKeyEvent: (node, event) {print(e); ....` and it prints down and up events (just found that `onKey` should not be used as it uses legacy API)

Comment: updated again with what you have, and it's not detecting anything. ..I don't know why?

Comment: maybe it works for physical keyboard only? i am using "flutter desktop" / "flutter web" - are you by any chance using android / iOS with virtual kbd?

Comment: I'm developing on android....using android emulator. I tried using the soft keyboard in the android emulator as well as my physical keyboard, no luck. Strange.

Comment: OnKey does not work either.

Comment: tried overriding  `TextEditingController.buildTextSpan` and using `WidgetSpan` as one of the `children` of `TextSpan`?

Comment: @mikehennessy Did you found out a way to achieve that? I've been also looking for a solution and either of the examples above indeed do not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
int atCount = 0;
```

In your onChanged, just evaluate like this:

```
newAtCount = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<comment.length; i++) {
if (comment[i] == '@') {
newAtCount++;
}
if (newAtCount > atCount) {
//your function
}
atCount = newAtCount;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work, because it should only popup/show names to add when they hit @. Once they type another letter, it should disappear. Therefore can't use contains

Comment: I think you're missing the fact, that it needs to be anywhere within a given comment. Consider that you type the following "Good to see you yesterday, lets' connect". Then, you change your cursor to just after "you". and hit the @ key. this would need to be detected and popup list of names.

Comment: Following better now.  Just keep a count of @'s outside your onChanged, then each onChanged, count 'em again.  if one gets added, bring up your function.  Didn't include it, but if you're going to insert the name they select, maybe keep a list of index positions where the @ was, and insert the rest of the user name in the new position when selected.

Comment: Appreciate the idea, but it's a bit of a hack.  Being able to detect keypress has to be supported in Flutter (it is), but just having issues getting it working on a textformfield.

Comment: Yep. In your first example, assign the FocusNode focusNode = FocusNode(); and then FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNode);  I see you're missing that.  Not used the rawkeyboardlistener, but might help.

Answer (score 0):

Use a controller and in the controller, there is a selection property that shows the cursor position.

> If the selection is collapsed, then this property gives the offset of the
> cursor within the text.

```
_controller.addListener(() {
  if (!_controller.selection.isCollapsed ||
      _controller.text.isEmpty ||
      _controller.selection.end <= 0) {
    return;
  }
  var lastPressedCharacter =
      _controller.text.characters.elementAt(_controller.selection.end - 1);
  this.onNewKeyPressed?.call(lastPressedCharacter);
});
```

Comment: how do you get backspace or delete or enter in this case?

Comment: This is a workaround if you are using TextField, if you need every key press, you have to use other methods.